# Bessel Function Identity $\frac{d}{dx}[x(J_pJ_{-p}'-J_{-p}J'_{p})]=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, bessel-functions

I'm attempting to show the following identity for Bessel functions:

> $$\frac{d}{dx}[x(J_pJ_{-p}'-J_{-p}J'_{p})]=0$$

I've taken 3 approaches:

- Brute force using the series definitions (things got unwieldy)
- Expanding out the product rule
- Substituting various identities and recurrence relations

I can't get it to work

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s a Jacobian. Look up Abel’s theorem

Comment: Give more detail please!